# Does install4j command line tool work on a 32-bit JVM on Linux?

Tags: install4j

Install4j works for us from the command line in headless mode on Linux when running on a 64-bit JVM.

Today we tried a 32-bit JVM, and we got this message at startup:

```
[13:56:51][Step 1/1] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk1.7.0_71_32/jre/lib/i386/libfontmanager.so: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:61)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.<clinit>(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at sun.font.SunFontManager$1.run(SunFontManager.java:339)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at sun.font.SunFontManager.<clinit>(SunFontManager.java:335)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:264)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1027)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1624)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRadioButtonUI.getPreferredSize(BasicRadioButtonUI.java:231)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1660)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at com.ejt.framework.gui.ck.<clinit>(ejt:36)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.main(ejt:93)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1]    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
[13:56:51][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
```

Is there something we can do to make this work?

The file /opt/jdk1.7.0_71_32/jre/lib/i386/libfontmanager.so exists and has proper permissions (rwxr-xr-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by executing the following line in bash:

```
yum install libgcc_s.so.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the 32bit version of the packages required by the 32bit JVM are missing on your 64bit OS.